How to Increase the Size of the Loading Circle in Dash Plotly

I am working on a Dash Plotly application where I have a dcc.Loading component to show a loading circle while a scatter plot is being loaded. However, I want to increase the size of the loading circle. Here is the relevant part of my code:

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

html.Div([
    html.Div(id='timer-output'),
    dcc.Loading(
        dcc.Graph(id="scatter-plot"),
        type="circle",
        style={'filter': 'blur(0px)'},  # Add blur effect to loading overlay
    ),
], style={'margin-left': '30%', 'width': '70%', 'margin-right': '90px', 'margin-top': '80px'})

I've tried adding a blur effect to the loading overlay using CSS, but I can't figure out how to increase the size of the loading circle. I looked through the Dash documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a direct way to set the size of the loading spinner.
Is there a way to customize the size of the loading circle in Dash? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

.custom-loading-spinner > div {
    width: 60px !important;
    height: 60px !important;
    border-width: 8px !important;
}

i just created a custom css for this and it works for me
